# How can I hide edition menu from modern Sharepoint site?

Tags: modern-team-site, menu, modern

I would like to hide this menu for all user except owners in Modern Sharepoint Sites:

[image: Editor menu]

If it is not possible, is it possible at least hide the publication date and editing info?

Thank you!